# ¿Cómo conseguir rellenar 40 puntos en campos numéricos en C#?

Tags: c#

Buenas a todos y a todas.

He comenzado a estudiar nuevos lenguajes de programación y entre ellos está C#.

Como actividad, nos han mandado a realizar una ficha de personajes con este lenguaje en Visual Studio.

Ahora mismo, estoy realizando algunas funciones y, mi intención, es poder conseguir completar la tarea. Para ello, necesito hacer un apartado de características que explico a continuación:

- Las características dependen de la especialidad de profesión elegida (no tendrá la misma vida un elementarista que un guardián, por ejemplo.
- Cuando el usuario selecciona la especialidad, las características de esa raza son cargados por defecto teniendo la posibilidad de añadir hasta 40 puntos extra en alguna de las características.
- Una vez el usuario pulsa en cualquiera de los campos numéricos, los puntos deberían aumentar o disminuir en función de lo que seleccionamos.

Dicho esto, lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

He creado campos numericupdown en un groupbox. Estos campos están deshabilitados hasta que el usuario selecciona la especialidad.

Una vez comienza a añadir valores extra, la variable de puntos decrece (aunque no sé cómo incrementarla) en función de lo que el usuario seleccione (arriba o abajo).

Dejo el código a continuación:

```
 //Funcion para rellenar las caracteristicas en funcion de la seleccion que hemos hecho
    public void rellenarCaracteristicas(String seleccion)
    {

        numbVida.Enabled = true;
        numbAD.Enabled = true;
        numbDef.Enabled = true;
        numbSpeed.Enabled = true;
        numbRegen.Enabled = true;
        numbMana.Enabled = true;
        numbVida.Minimum = 100;
        numbAD.Minimum = 100; 
        numbDef.Minimum = 100;
        numbSpeed.Minimum = 100;
        numbRegen.Minimum = 100;
        numbMana.Minimum = 100;
        numbDef.Maximum = 400;
        numbSpeed.Maximum = 400;
        numbRegen.Maximum = 400;
        numbMana.Maximum = 400;
        numbAD.Maximum = 400;
        numbVida.Maximum = 400;
        //Segun lo que seleccionamos, cargamos unas estadisticas u otras
        switch (seleccion)
        {
            case "Guardián":
                numbVida.Value = 400;
                numbAD.Value = 150;
                numbDef.Value = 300;
                numbSpeed.Value = 150;
                numbRegen.Value = 300;
                numbMana.Value = 200;
                break;
            case "Guerrero":
                numbVida.Value = 300;
                numbAD.Value = 350;
                numbDef.Value = 250;
                numbAD.Value = 150;
                numbSpeed.Value = 180;
                numbRegen.Value = 200;
                numbMana.Value = 180;
                break;
            case "Ingeniero":
                numbVida.Value = 250;
                numbAD.Value = 100;
                numbDef.Value = 200;
                numbSpeed.Value = 200;
                numbRegen.Value = 100;
                numbMana.Value = 100;
                break;
            case "Guardabosques":
                numbVida.Value = 290;
                numbAD.Value = 190;
                numbDef.Value = 150;
                numbSpeed.Value = 230;
                numbRegen.Value = 200;
                numbMana.Value = 180;
                break;
            case "Ladrón":
                numbVida.Value = 200;
                numbAD.Value = 220;
                numbDef.Value = 140;
                numbSpeed.Value = 300;
                numbRegen.Value = 100;
                numbMana.Value = 150;

                break;
            case "Elementarista":
                numbVida.Value = 245;
                numbAD.Value = 200;
                numbDef.Value = 170;
                numbSpeed.Value = 250;
                numbRegen.Value = 200;
                numbMana.Value = 300;
                break;
            case "Hipnotizador":
                numbVida.Value = 245;
                numbAD.Value = 200;
                numbDef.Value = 130;
                numbSpeed.Value = 250;
                numbRegen.Value = 200;
                numbMana.Value = 300;
                break;
            case "Nigromante":
                numbVida.Value = 245;
                numbAD.Value = 200;
                numbDef.Value = 160;
                numbSpeed.Value = 250;
                numbRegen.Value = 200;
                numbMana.Value = 300;
                break;
        }
        //Ponemos el número de puntos
        numPuntos = 40;
    }

    private void groupBoxCaracteristicas_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void numbVida_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Al cambiar el valor de cualquiera de los numeric (he selecionado todos los numeric para que copien a este)
        if (numPuntos != 0)
        {
            numPuntos--;
            lblGasto.Text = numPuntos.ToString();
        }
```

}

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que aumente los puntos si el usuario pulsa en aumentar una característica? Ya que, como digo, no sé hacerlo porque la función onValueChanged es copiada por todos los numericupdown que tengo.

Gracias de antemano.

**Edit 1:**

Tras la respuesta, he cambiado el método añadiendo una variable que recogerá el valor anterior:

```
 private void numbVida_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumericUpDown control = (NumericUpDown) sender;
        //Comprobamos si estamos incrementando o decrementando el valor

        if(control.Value > valorAnterior)
        {
            //Al cambiar el valor de cualquiera de los numeric (he selecionado todos los numeric para que copien a este)
            if (numPuntos != 0)
            {
                numPuntos--;
                lblGasto.Text = numPuntos.ToString();
            }else if(numPuntos == 0)
            {
                numbVida.Enabled = false;
                numbAD.Enabled = false;
                numbDef.Enabled = false;
                numbSpeed.Enabled = false;
                numbRegen.Enabled = false;
                numbMana.Enabled = false;
            }
        }else
        {
            if (numPuntos != 40)
            {
                numPuntos++;
                lblGasto.Text = numPuntos.ToString();
            }else if(numPuntos == 40)
            {
                //numbVida.Enabled = false;
                //numbAD.Enabled = false;
                //numbDef.Enabled = false;
                //numbSpeed.Enabled = false;
                //numbRegen.Enabled = false;
                //numbMana.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        valorAnterior = control.Value;

    }
```

El problema viene en que siempre entra en el if de numPuntos == 0 por lo que no puedo editar los campos (sin yo haber comenzado a cambiar los puntos).

En teoría, lo que aspiro a conseguir es lo siguiente:

Si has gastado 40 puntos, obviamente que no gastes más.
Si restas un punto a la habilidad, que los puntos se sumen (cosa que hago ya).
Si estás en 40 y bajas una característica, la variable de puntos no debería sumarse.

**Edit 2:**

Tras adoptar la nueva solución, encuentro otro problema. Si llegamos a 0 puntos y queremos asignar 1 punto a cualquiera de los controles (tenemos más de 1), me salta el mensaje de que no hay más puntos pero la variable de puntos aumenta su valor en 1, por lo que la siguiente vez que le demos asignamos 1 punto extra (cuando no se debería).

```
 private void numbVida_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //OJO! Este método no se llamará si el valor no cambia
        NumericUpDown control = (NumericUpDown)sender;
        int old_value = Int32.Parse(((UpDownBase)sender).Text);
        int new_value = (int)((NumericUpDown)sender).Value;
        bool aumenta = old_value < new_value ? true : false;
        if (aumenta) //si el nuevo valor es mayor al anterior
        {
            if (numPuntos > 0) //si hay más de cero puntos disponibles (1 o más)
            {
                numPuntos--;
                lblGasto.Text = numPuntos.ToString();
            }
            else  //si no hay más de cero, es decir si numpuntos es cero
            {
                control.Value = old_value;
                //revierto el nuevo valor del NumericUpDown y lo dejo con el valor anterior
                //porque no debería dejarme subir más puntos si ya ocupé los 40
                MessageBox.Show("No hay puntos adicionales disponibles");
            }
        }
        else //si el nuevo valor no es mayor (es menor)
        {
            //Si el número de puntos no es igual a 0, no hace falta sumar los puntos.
            if (numPuntos < 40)
            {
                numPuntos++;
                lblGasto.Text = numPuntos.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                control.Value = old_value; //lo mismo de arriba
                MessageBox.Show("No puede devolver más puntos");
            }
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entra en el numPuntos == 0 porque estás usando 'else if', y eso hará que haga la comprobación de nuevo, y arriba ya la hiciste entonces es innecesario repetirla porque los if solo tienen 2 respuestas..

```
if (numPuntos != 0) //aqui haces la pregunta
{
     numPuntos--;
     lblGasto.Text = numPuntos.ToString();
}
else if(numPuntos == 0) //aquí estás preguntando de nuevo
{

}
```

Solo cambia 'else if' por 'else'
(El if pregunta si es distinto, entonces el else se usará cuando sea lo contrario, es decir si es igual)

Respecto al método, ya lo había trabajado un poco y quedo algo parecido al tuyo, a ver si refinas tu código con esta ayuda.

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //OJO! Este método no se llamará si el valor no cambia
    NumericUpDown control = (NumericUpDown)sender;
    int old_value = Int32.Parse(((UpDownBase)sender).Text);
    int new_value = (int)((NumericUpDown)sender).Value;
    bool aumenta = old_value < new_value ? true : false;
    if (aumenta) //si el nuevo valor es mayor al anterior
    {
        if(numPuntos > 0) //si hay más de cero puntos disponibles (1 o más)
        {
            numPuntos--;
        }
        else  //si no hay más de cero, es decir si numpuntos es cero
        {
            control.Value = old_value; 
           //revierto el nuevo valor del NumericUpDown y lo dejo con el valor anterior
           //porque no debería dejarme subir más puntos si ya ocupé los 40
            MessageBox.Show("No hay puntos adicionales disponibles");
        }
    }
    else //si el nuevo valor no es mayor (es menor)
    {
        if(numPuntos < 40)
        {
            numPuntos++;
        }
        else 
        {
            control.Value = old_value; //lo mismo de arriba
            MessageBox.Show("No hay puntos adicionales disponibles");
        }
    }

    puntos.Text = numPuntos.ToString();
}
```

Acabo de armar todo un proyecto para probarlo y me funciona, así que ve si lo entiendes y te sirve para familiarizarte más con C#

Nota: puntos.Text es un label, lo puse para ver cuando puntos libres quedaban para asignar.

Saludos.

Comment: Tu solución es válida al 90%. Funciona muy bien, muchas gracias. Eso sí, cuando llegas a 0 puntos y quieres asignar más, te salta el mensaje pero la variable (que vale 0) se incrementa igualmente por lo que falsamente puedes añadir un punto adicional la próxima vez que quieras incrementar. En la pregunta dejo la edición para que lo veas.

Answer (score 1):

En el código *numbVida_ValueChanged_1* estás dando por hecho que hay que quitar puntos a la variable numPuntos, es decir, estás sentando que todos los NumericUpDown van a aumentar su valor, pero no restarlo (podría subirle 40 puntos a un solo control pero luego quitárselos).

Por lo tanto deberías comprobar, en primer lugar, si estás incrementando o disminuyendo el valor, con eso ya podrías solventar el problema de incrementar el valor de numPuntos.

Ahora bien, si usas el mismo evento (numbVida_ValueChanged_1) para todos los NumericUpDown pero quieres diferenciar el resultado, entonces debes diferenciar el origen, con el 'sender' puedes obtener el NumericUpDown que inició el evento, solo debes castearlo al empezar el evento:

```
NumericUpDown control = (NumericUpDown) sender;
```

Y con eso ya puedes aumentar o disminuir su valor sin afectar las demás características y al mismo tiempo manejar la variable numPuntos.

Espero te sirva, pues creo haber entendido la pregunta, un saludo.

Comment: Creo que he entendido bien. El problema es que intento hacer la lógica del programa y no funciona. Actualizo el post.

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta rapida.. Sabes cual es el total de puntos de cada clase.. sabes cual es el total de puntos cuando sumas los 40..

Guarda en una variable el total, has la suma cada vez que hay un cambio, y muestra la diferencia siempre.